# How to plot Topics' triggetings

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I want chart/graph to to see at which time whicht topic triggered. e.g I have a topic t1 which bublishes strings "yes" and sometimes "no". Another topic t2 publishes string "why" only when t1 bublishes "no". Now I want to get a chart/graph. When and which topic triggered. I have seen the rxplot (only works for numeric values). rxconsole gives the output but in a seraial form. Is there any way you know how to get my desired plot OR how to get a text file from rxconsole so that i can play with in Matlab to get the plot. I mean I am only interested triggering of the topic but on some specific values.
Any clues please?
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33768/how-to-plot-topics%27-triggetings/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unaware of any tool that's exactly like that. rxbag will do some of the things your asking for.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0